# create update review with sequelize in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a database in sequelize.js and I am able to create a review in that database. But when I try to do an update at that time I am not able to do this. It's shown in postman that the review edited successfully but not updated in the database.

Here is my code for update review:

```
app.put("/reviews/:id", async(req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.rating_ID;
    DB.Rating.update(
        {
          review:req.params.review,
          ratingScore:req.params.ratingScore,
    }, { where: { id:req.body.rating_ID }
        }).then(() => res.send("Review Editted Successfully"));
    });
```

Comment: Hi, in the route you are getting only '/:id' param, but in your code you using "req.params.review" and "req.params.ratingScore", Please do a console.log(req.params) to verify,

Comment: Hello, I did console.log(req.params) and it gives me a number of id means show me rating_ID which I use to update the review and still didn't update the review in database